# Is it possible to make passing tests a requirement for releasing new application versions?

Tags: origen-sdk

My team uses `origen rc tag` to release new versions of our applications, however we don't have a continuous integration system running to automatically check that a given application's test suite is passing before we release.

Sometimes we have released new versions which have bugs which could have been caught by enforcing that all tests must pass before executing the release.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes-- we generally use `origen specs` or `origen examples` as part of our application's `validate_release` call-back method.  This causes these sorts of checks to run and pass before release will be permitted.

See details as to the [Origen SDK Release Process](http://origen-sdk.org/origen//guides/misc/callbacks/?highlight=validate_release#Release_Process).

The `specs` command is one where you have set up unit tests in your app.  More on that here:  [Dev Considerations : Unit Testing](http://origen-sdk.org/origen//guides/plugins/development/?highlight=rspec#Add_Tests).